# WooCommerce create new product and add to cart on form submit

Tags: plugins, functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I am customizing woo-commerce plugin to add product from the front end into the cart. I have written the function in functions.php, but i am getting a Fatal error.

Getting this error-->

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_to_cart() on a non-object
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\cutting-edge_server\wordpress_theme\wp-content\themes\cutting_age\responsive\functions.php
>   on line 56

Any body have any idea how to resolve it?

My function.php file

```
if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"]))
        {
       echo $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING];
      // echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
        echo "i am in if";
        //exit();
    add_filter('woocommerce_before_cart', 'customcart');

    function customcart() { 
       echo "i am in function";

    //global $woocommerce;

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'

    );


    // Insert the post into the database
     $product_ID=wp_insert_post( $my_post );

     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100, $unique);
     add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100, $unique);
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock', $unique);


      //Getting error on this line.
      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );




     exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "cart" ) ) );
    }

    customcart();
      }
```

My html file

```
<form name="addpro" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="addcustomcarts" value="ADD TOO CART" />
  </form>
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment `//global $woocommerce;`?

Comment: getting same error.. @toscho

Comment: you have any idea????@toscho

Comment: 1. I already did provide a suggestion on your original question in SO where you asked the exact same thing. 2. I voted to close your question as I already told you in SO that it would be off topic here. 3. You're hijacking someone else's question for your personal gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but the following code did work for me in that it created a new product and added it to the cart. Note, I had to use `$_GET` to test on my setup since I don't have the rest of your code and didn't feel like creating a form.

**EDIT**: I've added a simple `<form>` element and switched to `$_POST`. 
**EDIT 2**: I've removed the form. Apparently the OP has the form on the front page.

```
add_action('init', 'customcart');

function customcart() {

  if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"])) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'My post',
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    if ( $product_ID ){
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );

      //Getting error on this line.
      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

      exit( wp_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) ) );

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: i have a form with on submit button and form method is post

Comment: your code is not working i used post instead of get

Comment: Are you sure your form set to post? Because, I've switched to `$_POST` and once I click 'Submit' the post is inserted and added to the cart.

Comment: see this my form  <form name="addpro" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="addcustomcarts" value="ADD TOO CART" />
  </form>

Comment: can you share your code what exactly you made the changes in function.php

Comment: My code is already posted above. Also you should edit your question with your form code, as it can be hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: I don't believe the submit button's value is posted. See my edited code and try that.

Comment: you can check it i have added my html form in the bottom side

Comment: I have tried your form, and the submit button's value is not posted. Please try what I have suggested.

Comment: what you write this code in function.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11210/discussion-between-helgatheviking-and-sanjay-nakate)

Comment: hey you are genius...................

Comment: You have any idea about woo commerce email attachment.

Comment: add_action('init', 'customcart'); instead of  'init' hook it will work with 'template_redirect'

Answer (score 0):

The $woocommerce->cart apparently is not an object during the call. Set it to get checked before the line that gives the error:

```
    if( $woocommerce->cart )
      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );
```

This will make sure the cart is even there and won't execute the line if it's not.

Comment: its work but when redirect through exit( wp_redirect( home_url( "cart"))); its saying that your cart is empty

Comment: it works but when i redirect to the cart page its  showing that your cart is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_to_cart_on_custom_page_and_redirect');
 
function add_to_cart_on_custom_page_and_redirect(){
 
    if( is_page( 'my-page' ) ) { // you can also pass a page ID instead of a slug
 
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 72 ); // add to cart product with ID 72
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
        exit();
 
    }
 
}
```